# Android - I dont know why my intent doesnt work

Tags: android

So, hello guys I'm new to here and also to android but I been searching for 3 years now on StackOverflow since I first started programming on my school, at the moment I'm stuck in this problem for 2 weeks because my intent to start an activity just doesn't work, I search a lot and saw several videos and I just can't figure it out, I didn't learn Android at all at school that's why I am doing a project on it,I really enjoy programming and learning.~

So my project consists of building a database to an app on Android (obviously) and a website which I'm also currently working on WordPress, my app and website are made for restaurants, cafes , similar to something like a pizza hut website but better (if I can make it I will show you guys). Well, I'm sorry I just thought I need to introduce my "work" and myself.

**Let's get to the point:**

I have this image that shows you my nightmare that is probably so simple to solve.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEUvH.png]

```
protected void cl_login (View view)
{
    txt_email.requestFocus();

    if(txt_email.getText().toString().equals("") == false && txt_pw.getText().toString().equals("") == false ) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "A entrar..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent ploginconta = new Intent(this, login_conta.class);
        startActivity(ploginconta);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tem de preencher os campos para entrar na sua conta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txt_pw.setText("");
        txt_email.setText("");
    }
}
protected void cl_semconta (View view)
{
    Intent paginaregisto = new Intent(this, registar.class);
    startActivity(paginaregisto);
}
protected void cl_esqueceupw (View view)
{
    Intent paginaesqueceupw = new Intent(this, esqueceu_pw.class);
    startActivity(paginaesqueceupw);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    txt_pw = findViewById(R.id.txt_pw);
    txt_email = findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    bt_login = findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
}
```

**LAYOUT 1**

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".login">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_linha3"
    android:layout_width="399dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.466"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rtl_login"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/txt_view_linha" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rtl_pwesquecida"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:onClick="cl_esqueceupw"
    android:text="@string/pwesquecida"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    app:fontFamily="@font/allerta"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rtl_ntemconta"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_login"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_redondo"
    android:onClick="cl_login"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_pw" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_email"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_email"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="EMAIL"
    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rtl_login" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_pw"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pw"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="PALAVRA-PASSE"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_email" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rtl_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:fontFamily="@font/biryani_extralight"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rtl_ntemconta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:onClick="cl_semconta"
    android:text="@string/naotemconta"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    app:fontFamily="@font/allerta"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_login"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and also the activity that I'm trying to start ( I changed only a bit of code in here)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y99Bc.png]

```
     public class login_conta extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_conta);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_conta, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_promocao) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_takeaway) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_domicilio) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_definicoes) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_avaliacao) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacte) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**LAYOUT 2**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_login_conta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/vw_conta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_login_conta"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_login_conta_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I really hope you guys help me out I because I can't find the error on the code or what should I do because again I'm really new to Android Studio I'm learning by searching I do and trying, please don't flame me and thank you.

**MY ANDROID MANIFEST:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aluno.pap">
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".esqueceu_pw"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".pap">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login_conta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_conta"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".login" />
    <activity android:name=".registar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Hey David, please share your code as text not as picture, preferably enough code for a [MCVE]. This will definitely improve your chances of getting a helpful answer while reducing the risk of being flamed to a minimum :-)

Comment: try using debuggers and find out where error occurs.

Comment: @0X0nosugar u are right, I am sorry, should I edit it now with the code under the picture?

Comment: IMO it's better to remove the pictures, we don't really need them: they can't be searched so text is better for future readers with a similar problem and they can't be copied to a sample app so we can't use them to reproduce your error or to test possible solutions

Comment: Im trying to put the code but Im having issues with it I dont know how to put it because alway get a error I thought I just needed to copy and paste it here?

Comment: I just got it, thank you for ur advice and help.

Comment: The MainActivity code is not exactly what I'd call a [MCVE]: there are methods which are not related to your current issue and there are some lines missing (the Java class is not complete) Since you seem to use OnClickListeners, we'd like to see how you set them, please share the layout file as well. And, last not least: what is the problem? Is there a crash? (If yes, you should post the crash log) Or does clicking have no effect? Or...?

Comment: Yes there is a crash, the application close say its stopping. Ill put the layout code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you AndroidManifest.xml file has the login_conta activity declared.
Something like this.

```
<activity android:name=".login_conta" />
```

Note: Use better naming for activity. for example, LoginActivity and LoginContaActivity. (I don't know what is login_conta).

Comment: Hello thank you for responding I do need to use better naming my teachers always warned me about that, I had already my activity with that name do u have any more suggestion? I'll be glad to hear it, login_conta its my login account after logging in.

Comment: do you have this activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Add screenshot of your AndroidManifest.xml file as well.

Comment: I write it as a code now and thank you for being so patient.